# Android: Canvas drawPath method draws solid background instead of transparent one

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

I'm just getting started with Android graphics and comprehensively stuck on this problem.  I'm working on a drawing app at the moment and I'll expand it to something cooler once I have the basics working.

I'm trying to draw a path onto an existing image (which contains all previous paths) but the rectangle represented by the boundaries of the path is drawn as a solid shape at the same time, overwriting bits of the background image.

I'm using the following command to invalidate my canvas and draw the required update:

```
invalidate
(
    (int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
    (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
    (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
    (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH)
);
```

and in my onDraw I've got the following:

```
if (drawing.size() > 0) //if there are paths
{
    canvas.drawPath(drawing.get(drawing.size() - 1), paint); //draw the latest path
}
```

I could just draw all paths in my drawing (defined as LinkedList of path objects), but that's very slow.  I just want to draw the latest path onto the canvas, without any silly rectangle appearing around the path.

I've tried canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) before my call to drawPath, but it didn't help.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Look into porterduff mode, it allows you to blend